# Como listar as tabelas que contem valores nulos em um banco oracle?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Quais tabelas contêm valores nulos?
Minha lógica foi:

```
SELECT *
FROM all_tables;
WHERE table IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Certo, primeiro vamos entender o que você quer dizer por nulo, acredito que existem duas formas de interpretar sua questão:

- Uma tabela sem registros
- Uma tabela cujo a coluna X esteja sem registros.

No caso de uma tabela sem registros você pode realizar uma consulta para ver o número de registros que ela possui, algo como:

```sql
select tab.owner as schema_name,
       tab.table_name
from sys.all_tables tab
where num_rows is null 
      or num_rows = 0
      -- excluding some Oracle maintained schemas
      and owner not in ('ANONYMOUS','CTXSYS','DBSNMP','EXFSYS', 'LBACSYS', 
      'MDSYS', 'MGMT_VIEW','OLAPSYS','OWBSYS','ORDPLUGINS', 'ORDSYS',
      'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA','SYS','SYSMAN','SYSTEM', 'TSMSYS','WK_TEST',
      'WKPROXY','WMSYS','XDB','APEX_040000', 'APEX_PUBLIC_USER','DIP', 
      'FLOWS_30000','FLOWS_FILES','MDDATA', 'ORACLE_OCM', 'XS$NULL',
      'SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR', 'SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR', 'PUBLIC',
      'WKSYS', 'OUTLN')
order by schema_name, 
         table_name;
```

[Fonte](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/oracle/find-empty-tables-in-database)

No caso de uma tabela com colunas nulas você pode realizar uma consulta como:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tabela WHERE coluna IS NULL;
```

O que você pode fazer se quiser, é executar o [DBMS_STATS  gather_database_stats](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68569) e depois executar a seguinte consulta na tabela `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
 WHERE NULLABLE = 'Y' AND 
      NUM_DISTINCT = 0
```

[Fonte da ideia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627938/oracle-finding-columns-with-only-null-values)